# Compares array and array of obj

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object

Hello everyone i have this obj

```
const responseFilms = {
      "page": 1,
      "results": [
        {
          "adult": false,
          "backdrop_path": "/cinER0ESG0eJ49kXlExM0MEWGxW.jpg",
          "genre_ids": [28, 12, 14],
          "id": 566525,
          "title": "Test movie",
          "video": false,
          "vote_average": 7.8,
          "vote_count": 1726
        },
        {
          "adult": false,
          "backdrop_path": "/cinER0ESG0eJ49kXlExM0MEWGxW.jpg",
          "genre_ids": [35, 16, 14],
          "id": 566525,
          "title": "Test movie",
          "video": false,
          "vote_average": 7.8,
          "vote_count": 1726
        }
      ]

}
```

And then i have another array of object like this

```
const responseGenres = [
{id: 28, name: 'Action'},
{id: 12, name: 'Adventure'}
{id: 14, name: 'Fantasy'}
{id: 35, name: 'Comedy'}
{id: 16, name: 'Animation'}
]
```

what i would like to get is, for each genre_ids which is inside results which is inside the first object,
I would like to create a new array of objects formatted like this

```
const newARR = [
        {
          "adult": false,
          "backdrop_path": "/cinER0ESG0eJ49kXlExM0MEWGxW.jpg",
          "genre_ids": [28, 12, 14],
          "GENRE_NAME":["action","adventure","fantasy"]
          "id": 566525,
          "title": "Test movie",
          "video": false,
          "vote_average": 7.8,
          "vote_count": 1726
        },
        {
          "adult": false,
          "backdrop_path": "/cinER0ESG0eJ49kXlExM0MEWGxW.jpg",
          "genre_ids": [35, 16, 14],
          "GENRE_NAME":["Comedy","Animation","fantasy"]
          "id": 566525,
          "title": "Test movie",
          "video": false,
          "vote_average": 7.8,
          "vote_count": 1726
        }
      ]
```

then insert the new GENRE_NAME key inside.
What I have written so far is this, but then I totally freeze

```
 const setTrendFilm = async () => {
    const dataTrendFilm = await fetch(
      api_base + api_key 
    );
    const genres = await fetch(
      api_base2 + api_key
    );

    const responseFilms = await dataTrendFilm.json();
    const responseGenres = await genres.json();

    const formattedFilms = [];

    responseFilms.results.map((film) => {
      return film.genre_ids.map((element) => {
        return responseGenres.genres.filter((genre) => genre.id === element)
          .name;
      });
    });
    console.log(responseFilms);
  };
```

Comment: possible but will take some time to implement logic

Answer (score 0):

initial way is like this, solve one step by step

```
var GENRE_NAME = []
responseFilms.results.map((film, index) => {
  film.genre_ids.map((element) => {
    GENRE_NAME[index] = responseGenres.filter((genre) => genre.id === element).map(e=>e.name);
  });
});
```

the build your object,

```
var j = {}
var obj = responseFilms.results
for(var key in obj){
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    var val = obj[key];
    j[key]=val;
  }  
}
for(let i=0;i<GENRE_NAME.length;i++){
  j["GENRE_NAME"] = GENRE_NAME[i]
}
```

Comment: unfortunately this does not return the expected result. Instead, it returns an array of objects equal to response film at the end of which c is an array with a ["thriller"] element.